# Salesforce ServiceM8 Integration

Tags: api, salesforce, integration

We had already integrated Salesforce and ServiceM8. We have been pushing a custom object into servicem8 and creating a job.

This was working well before but not for last few days. We get the below error while posting.

Error:
{"errorCode":400,"message":"Bad Request. No data received in POST"}

Can you please identify what does this mean?

NOTE: We have been sending this in JSON format. We tried with the example that ServiceM8 given in the API document. That itself didn't get posted now.

Please assist, if there is any changes in the serviceM8 api.

I am passing the content type through header. Please find the sample request and response below.

Request===System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/job/0bd2a066-8ac8-4d0c-83db-2deb78973ceb.json, Method=POST]

JSON String==={"status":"Completed","purchase_order_number":null,"job_description":"","job_address":"test, test, test, test, test","customfield_strata_number":"Yes","customfield_service_sheet_url":"SS2000420","customfield_salesforce_id":"012038","customfield_purchase_order_number":null,"customfield_notes_to_service":null,"customfield_notes_from_previous_service":null,"customfield_message_to_technician":null,"customfield_booking_notes":null,"customfield_booked_with_customer":"Yes","company_uuid":"15792888-b2f4-4538-a325-c3a58defaddb","badges":"[\"64cb190d-6a08-4ce2-ab08-56d8999c8a8b\",\"2aec7e2e-7370-42d0-9ea2-f16a859a2d1b\",\"a225a59f-b21f-4ea1-bce7-5e28ff2bd89b\",\"e71de9ce-8207-4bdd-a178-f05f35c675cb\",\"62795263-6867-45d8-868f-ab8cfbcf897b\",\"08b0cfa0-2d9c-438e-b7b0-ba41a437607b\",]"}

Response:
VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|{"errorCode":400,"message":"Bad Request. No data received in POST"}

Comment: Either your integration isn't sending the appropriate content-type header to match the format of the request body ("Content-type: application/json" if you're sending JSON data), or the data that is being sent isn't able to be decoded. The most common cause of this is invalid character encoding or unescaped quotes in JSON data. You would need to post an example request + response log in order to determine which one of these is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Telomore for your comments. I am passing the content type through header. Now, I have updated this question with the Request and Response that get. Please assist on this

Comment: Using your request/response log I was able to reproduce the 400 error you're seeing by setting the Content-type header in the request to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". When I set this to "application/json" the error is resolved. I suggest you double-check that you are setting this header correctly in your request.